# Azure .NET Backend from Scratch?

Tags: .net, azure, mobile, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Azure does not contain a documentation for setting up a .NET Backend for Mobile from scratch. All I keep seeing is this 'TodoItem' example and it's very frustrating.

> I'm trying to connect it to an existing Azure SQL DB
>
> The table that I'm trying to retrieve data from is 'UserTable'

This is what my model looks like:

```
public class UserTable : EntityData
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserFName { get; set; }
        public string UserLName { get; set; }

}
```

Now how do I create a fresh backend for my scenario instead of all these TodoItem projects that it auto loads when I create a new Mobile Backed Project from VS2013? No documentations on the web whatsoever. Thank you so much!

EDIT:

According to my iOS developer He the JSON Response in a format such as this:

```
[{
   status:true,
   message: "Successfully Logged in",
   values:{
       email: user@sample.com,
       password: samplepassword,
       accesstoken: 7h234b7b2j
     }
}]
```

So therefore when a user logs in, an access token needs to be added to the response as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very long and detailed tutorial on how to build a mobile service using an existing SQL database with the Mobile Services .NET backend at this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/. There is documentation, you just have to dig a bit.

App Services are still new and not all scenarios have been documented yet, so it helps to go back to the Mobile Services docs. I assume that you are familiar with ASP.NET WebAPI because that is exactly what a .NET backend is for Azure mobile (services or apps). If not, I recommend you ramp-up on WebAPI starting here: http://www.asp.net/web-api.

Comment: I'm Chris from the Mobile product team. We should have some new content out soon and we're working hard to make this scenario easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for that link. I will read it. Also check my EDIT please.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT What can you say about my new EDIT? How can I assign access tokens and send in that JSON format?

Comment: I responded to your question in detail on MSDN. I don't think you should do this on the server side given that the client side SDK expects the flat-table format. Also, please don't store passwords in plaintext. :)

Comment: Oh hello nice to see you on stack as well Chris! haha. Yes I took that in to account, mate. I posted a response on msdn, could you go through that when you can please? :) @ChrisAnderson-MSFT

Comment: We're trying out some new forum monitoring tools on App Service. Makes it easy to be everywhere. :) I've responded. I think you and the iOS developer should take a look at the iOS client SDK and see if there is really a need for what you're asking for. The client SDK already helps handle errors. They might be used to working with a plain WebAPI, but we're a bit fancier.